# C++ Return Statement Not Working

Tags: c++, return

I've just started learning C++ and i've been having problems implementing return statements. I've been easily able to pass data to a new function but I am having no joy in getting it to return.

I've written the simplest code I could think of to try and debug what is going wrong and I still can't work it out. I am NOT trying to pass too many return values and I have a correct function type to pass too. It just doesn't seem to work?

I am using Xcode 4 on a Macbook Pro:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int agenext (int age);

int main ()
{   int age;
    cout << "What's Your Age? \n";
    cin >> age;
    cout << "Your Current Age: " << age;
    agenext(age);
    cout << endl << "A year has passed your new age is: ";
    cout << age;
}

int agenext (int x)
{
    x++;
    cout << endl << "Your Next Birthday is " << x;
    return x;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question (which has already been answered), but you might find it useful. You say you've written the simplest code you could to debug the problem, but there's room for more simplification. [Here's a demo](https://gist.github.com/Keith-S-Thompson/6692473). I've removed the user input and trimmed the output to just what's needed to show the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return`ing is only half the battle, the other half is assigning that value to something.  Consider changing:

```
agenext(age);
```

to

```
age = agenext(age);
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense :) Thanks for such prompt responses.

Answer (score 4):

It's returning perfectly find. You just aren't setting the value it returns to anything.

```
age = agenext(age)
```

Is what you are looking for, or you could pass a pointer or a reference to the `age` variable.

Answer (score 2):

Both the existing answers are correct; if you want to `return` a value, it needs to be assigned somewhere.

For future reference, you can also do what you want by skipping the `return` and passing `age` by reference instead of value.

```
void agenext (int &x)
{
    x++;
    cout << endl << "Your Next Birthday is " << x;
    /* the value change WILL show up in the calling function */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main function, you need another variable to hold the new age that is return from the age function.

```
int main ()
{   int age, newAge;
    cout << "What's Your Age? \n";
    cin >> age;
    cout << "Your Current Age: " << age;
    newAge = agenext(age);
    cout << endl << "A year has passed your new age is: ";
    cout << newAge;
    return 0;
}
```